# Why did this regex fail to match?

Tags: c#, regex

I tested a regex using:

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(txtToMatch.Text,txtRegex.Text,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 if (match.Success) {               
      MessageBox.Show("success");
 }
```

The regex that was used was `/d`. However, when I tested it on `9` it returned false. Why is this so?

Comment: thanks. i acidentally added "" around it twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is `\d`, rather than `/d`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\d`, not `/d`. To avoid getting your string treated as an escape sequence by C#, you could use a verbatim string: `@"\d"`.

Comment: There isn't, but it still gets treated as one, causing an error: "CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence '\d'".